# good and efficient way to replace list of char in string

Tags: c#, optimization

I want to replace some char `{'z', 'x', 'q'}` with *blank* in string below is my code

```
string input = "xeatq"

char[] words = new char[] { 'y', 'x', 'q' };

foreach (char c in words)
    input = input.Replace(c.ToString(), "");

return input;
```

but i think it's *not efficient* way to replace many data string (in my case a *million* data), it's so *slow*. Any *effecient* way to do my, can you provide me with the best way ?

Comment: A `RegularExpression` is likely to be significantly faster than this if you are executing it repeatedly.  In addition, why not use an array of `string` instead of `char` (rather than using `ToString()` each time)?

Comment: can you give me the sample

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, "z|x|q", string.Empty)`

Comment: how about effeciency ?

Comment: @DzarrahDeveloper Since you care about efficiency, why not use BenchmarkDotNet to compare the different answers here, and post your findings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple *Linq* should do:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// All characters which are not in words
input = string.Concat(input.Where(c => !words.Contains(c)));
```

If you have a *very long* `input` string and *huge* `words` and thus you want to optimize

```
// We explictly build the string; input.Length - to allocate memory just once
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length); 

// HashSet is more efficient for Contains than array: O(1) vs. O(N)
HashSet<char> hs = new HashSet<char>(words);

foreach (char c in input)
  if (!hs.Contains(c))
    sb.Append(c);

input = sb.ToString();
```

**Edit:** If you want to *change* one character into some `string` (see comments below), try `Dictionary<char, string>`, e.g.

```
 Dictionary<char, string> map = new Dictionary<char, string>() {
   {'x', "XX"}, // change x into "XX"
   {'y', ""},   // remove y
   {'z', ""},   // remove z
 };

 // Now input.Length is estimation; you may want to put, say input.Length + 1000  
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length); 

 foreach (var c in input) {
   if (map.TryGetValue(c, out var v))
     sb.Append(v);
   else 
     sb.Append(c);
 }

 input = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: How about effeciency

Comment: Bear in mind that `string.Concat` uses a `StringBuilder` internally, but it acquires it from a cache. So if you're calling this repeatedly, chances are that using `string.Concat` will be cheaper than creating your own `StringBuilder`, even for large strings. As always, profile your actual use case!

Comment: @Dzarrah Developer: *replacing* character with `""` (*empty string*) is equal to *skipping* the character: `AxB` -> `AB` in both cases.

Comment: how about if i want to change it to x to g not blank space

Comment: @Dzarrah Developer: if you want to *map* symbols to a `string`s (say, `'x'` into `"XX"`), try using *Dictionary*, please, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative would be

```
input = new string(input.Select(c => words.Contains(c) ? "" : c).ToArray())
```

Comment: How about effeciency

Comment: your solution allocates a string on every itteration, so mine should be more efficient. Maybe you can measure it and post your results here